# Ex fire resist + magic fire resist

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does fire resist granted by an Extraordinary ability stack with magic granted from a magical source? Eg. a sorcerer's red draconic bloodline fire resist 5 + armor of resist fire 5 for a total of 10 fire resist. Ex is mundane, while the armor is magical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, different sources of Energy Resistance do not stack with one another, they overlap.

In this case, it should be reasonably clear from the Sorcerer bloodline granting the [Energy Resistance special ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Energy-Resistance), which does explicitly not stack with Energy Resistance granted by spells, and the Energy Resistance granted by [the armor enhancement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/energy-resistance) is mentioned as functioning "similar to the resist energy spell".

More generally, it is because stacking rules for this special ability are not defined, and thus defaults to the [general rule of not stacking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking). In other words, bonus types are not defined for Energy Resistance. One being magical and the other non-magical does not affect matters.